Is there a way I can print out the date when my SSRS report was last cached?
I am caching my report once every week as it takes forever to load. But I want my report users to be able to see the date when the data in the report was last refreshed. Is there a way I can add that date to my report?
Tried using Now but it just gives the date and time of when I am opening the SSRS report and not exactly when it was last cached.

Could you have a dataset which returns the value of GETDATE() and display that?

Usual obligatory note that SQL Server 2008 ran out of support over 5 years ago; you need to implement your upgrade plan that you should have finalised some 6 years ago. Using such an out of date, insecure, version of SQL Server is a significant concern for you, your colleagues and your clients.

You can get the last run details by querying the report server database.
Select  top 1 * from ExecutionLog
this table has all execution details and you can filter out your report with a join of the Catalog table.

Thank you but is there any way I can do this without accessing the Report Server?
